# Proof about dimension of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working my way through Strang's Linear Algebra text, and I'm starting to get tripped up right at the end of chapter 3.5.  I think I got 43, but I don't really understand 44 or 46.

## 43

Intersections and sums have dim(V)+dim(W)=dim(V$\cap$W)+dim(V+W).  Start with a basis u<sub>1</sub>, ... , u<sub>r</sub> for the intersection V$\cap$W. Extend with v<sub>1</sub>, ... , v<sub>s</sub> to a basis for V, and separately with w<sub>1</sub>, ... , w<sub>t</sub> to a basis for W.  *Prove that the u's and v's and w's together are independent.*  The dimensions have (r+s)+(r+t)=(r)+(r+s+t) as desired.

---

**Proof:**

If v's and u's make a basis for V, then u's and v's must be independent, from the definition of a basis.

If u's and w's make a basis for W, then u's and w's must be independent, from the definition of a basis.

Now we just need to show that no w's are dependent of v's.

Take any vector w<sub>i</sub>.  From the problem statement, it is not in V$\cap$W, because then it would be a u.  So it is in W, and not in V$\cap$W.  Therefore it cannot be a v.  Doing the same thing for u<sub>i</sub> shows that u<sub>i</sub> cannot be a w.  Therefore u, v, w are all independent.

The formula in the question works because we are simply counting the number of vectors in u, v, w.  The left-hand side double counts the u vectors, and the right hand side tacks on an extra set of u vectors with the dim(V$\cap$W) term.

---

## 44

Mike Artin suggested a neat higher-level proof of that dimension formula in Problem 43.  From all inputs v in V and w in W, the "sum transformation" produces v+w.  Those outputs fill the space V+W.  The nullspace contains all pairs v=u, w=-u, for vectors u in V$\cap$W.  (Then v+w=u-u=0).  So dim(V+W)+dim(V$\cap$W)=dim(V)+dim(W)  (*input dimension from v and W*) by the crucial formula:

dimension of outputs + dimension of nullspace = dimension of inputs

*Problem* For an m by n matrix of rank r, what are those 3 dimensions?  Outputs=column space.  This question will be answered in 3.6, can you do it now?

---

I think there might be a vocabulary gap on this one.  I don't really know what a sum transformation is, or what it's asking.

I guess since we're talking about Ax=b, then x is the inputs and b is the outputs.  Then it would make sense that all b's is just the column space of [v w].  Are we still saying that v and w aren't complete bases of V and W?  I'm not sure.  I just don't really get the question.

---

## 46

Suppose A is a 10x10 matrix, and A<sup>2</sup>=0 (zero matrix).  This means that the column space is contained in the ______.  If A has rank r, those subspaces have dimension r$\leq$10-r.  So the rank is r$\leq$5.

---

I can see why the matrix has to be rank$\leq$5.  It would have to reduce to something like the block matrix:

R=$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & I \\
0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$

where I is at most 5x5.  R<sup>2</sup>=0.  I don't see what it says about the column space, except that I guess dim(C(A))$\leq$5.  I'm having trouble filling in the blank though.

Answer (score 3):

For **44.**, the 'sum transformation' process is just forming the sum, and it is talking about the linear map from $V\times W$ mapping $(v,w)\mapsto v+w$. 
Consider the range and the nullspace of this map. 
(Note that the space $V\times W$ of $(v,w)$ pairs can be regarded as the space $V\oplus W$ of '*formal sums*' of the form $v+w$ with $v\in V,\ w\in W$, and it has dimension $\ \dim V+\dim W$.)

For **46.**,  $\ A^2=0$ means that $A\cdot Ax=0$ for all vectors $x$. As we know, all the $Ax$'s form the column space, which is now contained in the *nullspace* of $A$ by the equation.

Comment: That makes sense about 46.  Thanks.  44 I'm still kind of shakey on.  How are we summing v and w?  (v,w)↦v+w could a series of all vi+wi (an mxi matrix) or just one big sum of every v and every w together at once (an mx1 column vector).